# Get content of h1 from external page with jquery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mediawiki where I would like to get the content from into another page. So I have:
http://bourlo.net/wiki/index.php/Lunet

And would like to display parts of this in a bootstrap modal on another page:
http://bourlo.net/stack/

The heading of the wiki page is retrieved by:

```
  $("#wikiModal h4.modal-title")
    .load( "http://bourlo.net/wiki/index.php/Lunet .firstHeading");
```

That works, yeah! But I don't want the complete

```
<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" lang="nl-informal">Lunet</h1>
```

In the `<h4>` from the modal, but only the content >>> Lunet

How can I do this?

Comment: `...load("http://bourlo.net/wiki/index.php/Lunet .firstHeading > *")`

Comment: @Moob `Lunet` is a text node, you cannot target it using a CSS/jQuery selector

Comment: @A.Wolff You're right. My bad ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use other ajax method instead. For the example:

```
$.get("http://bourlo.net/wiki/index.php/Lunet", function(html){
    var txt = $(html).find('.firstHeading').text();
    $("#wikiModal h4.modal-title").text(txt);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to extract the text only from your ajax returned text:

```
$.get( "http://bourlo.net/wiki/index.php/Lunet", function(html){

     $("#wikiModal h4.modal-title").text( $(html).find('.firstHeading').text() );
});
```

That's because you with `.load()`, you cannot manipulate the `responseText` before inserting into the DOM. Let's acknowledge that you can actually do something like this:

```
$h4 = $("#wikiModal h4.modal-title")
$h4
   .load( "http://bourlo.net/wiki/index.php/Lunet #firstHeading", function(){
        $h4.find('#firstHeading').replaceWith(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        });
    });
```

This is definitely more clumsy. But I bothered to put this out because, once in a while, you're constrained to use the `.load` version instead of the `.get` version by factors beyond your control.

Comment: What `html` are you referring to?

Comment: `function(html)` here it will be the `http://bourlo.net/wiki/index.php/Lunet` code page

Comment: Well, isn't that the only way you can get the remote page? And if you want a page portion, then only `.load` can do it. Yeah, so you load the entire page and begin DOM processing in place! And by the way, in any case, the more I look at my answer the more I  think its THE SAME as yours, essentially. Not so?

Comment: Your code should be: `$("#wikiModal h4.modal-title").text( $(html).find('.firstHeading').text() );` then it would work as expected by OP and then it would be the same as my answer. In your code, you weren't just adding the text of `.firstHeading` element but the whole code page (parsed so minus some elements as html, head, body)

Comment: Ooops! Of course, you're correct. You need to dive into the `.firstHeading`. Thank you.

Comment: I've added your proposal in a second button, see the difference: http://bourlo.net/stack/